# Why Jenkins fail to register dll after build?

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild

I am using Jenkins to build a solution, consisting of .NET projects,via MsBuild.exe and it fails with error `error CS0246` because it can't find a dll that was registered by one of the post-build steps of one of the projects in the solution file.

The post build register command is: `regsvr32 /s "C:\TFS\.......\MyDll.dll"`.
And the seems to be working fine with no error. Another project that comes next at the build order needs to load that dll, but is failing with the given error above.

When I build the solution manually or by batch it works fine.
**Why is it hapenning? Jenkins can't register dll's while building?**

Comment: I suggest you start by removing the `/s` flag when calling `regsvr32` to obtain some answer in case the registration fails.

Comment: Did you tried to register the dll without Jenkins with Jenkins user ? please try to set your user as Jenkins service and try again if it works it means the issue is permissions